# can we insert into two tables with single sql statement?

Tags: sql, mysql

Will it be possible to insert into two tables with same insert command?

Answer (score 9):

No you cannot perform multiple inserts into two tables in one query.

Answer (score 4):

No you can't.

If you want to ensure the atomicity of an operation that requires data to be inserted into 2 tables, you should protect it in a transaction. You either use the SQL statements `BEGIN TRAN` and `COMMIT TRAN`, or you use a transaction boundary in whatever language you're using to develop the db access layer. E.g. something like `Connection.StartTransaction` and `Connection.Commit` (or `Connection.Rollback` on an error).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe in a future release of MySQL you could create a View containing the 2 tables and insert into that.
But with MySQL 5.1.41 you'll get the error:
*"Can not modify more than one base table through a join view"*

But inserting into 2 tables with 1 query is a weird thing to do, and **I don't recommend it**.

For more on updatable views check out the [MySQL reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/view-updatability.html).

Comment: It is not weird to want to update (or insert into) multiple tables as part of a single atomic (i.e. all or nothing happens) operation. The more normalised your database, the more likely the need. You just need to protect the multiple updates in a db transaction.

Comment: True, but when I see a *single* insert statement, i will assume only 1 table is affected. The "weird" part applies to the 1 query aspect.

Answer (score 2):

You can call a stored procedure with inserts into two tables.

Comment: The answer is yes and this is how you do it. Useful when you have long  latency to your DB to combing several inserts into one statement.