# Generically identify the rowid causing a constraint conflict in SQLite

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlite, constraints, check-constraints

I need to identify the row that caused a constraint check to fail after an `INSERT OR IGNORE` statement.

I need this for a tool that generates SQL statements, so I can't tie this to a specific use case with a particular table.

The challenge here is that I can't know which constraints are set for the particular table that I will insert into. It may have foreign key or `UNIQUE` constraints, or even a `CHECK` clause attached.

So, all I can learn from the INSERT is that it has failed. Now, how to I tell which row broke the insert?

***Clarification:***

I'd need a solution that uses SQL statements / expressions, i.e. I cannot write non-SQL code around it.

***Bonus question in case it's impossible in SQLite:***

Can this be done in Postgresql or MySQL?

***Example use case***

Here's an example where this feature would be used (see the 2nd example and the note at the end which points back to this question): https://stackoverflow.com/a/53461201/43615

Comment: I don't know how to answer your exact requirement.  Maybe SQLite has logging which can be turned on.  If I had to find the offending row, offline, I would go into SQLite and run a query designed to flush out such rows.  Would that not be a possibility for you?

Comment: How exactly are the inserts done? Assume it has to be like some batch insert that pushes N rows at one command but how? Do all tables have any id/sequences even if not specific?

Comment: See the added link - it's about copying entire tables to a fresh set of tables, using an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger in which I then perform the optional `INSERT`, and where I then need to find the existing row if the insert failed. I'm writing a generator for this kind of conversion and need to make this as universal as possible. It's a near-impossible task to parse the original DB's schema to figure out all constraints and create the matching SELECT statements for those.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-exec.html#LIBPQ-EXEC-NONSELECT The  `PQPQresultVerboseErrorMessage()` function does what you want. You only need to parse its text body: `psycopg2.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "tt_payload_key"
DETAIL:  Key (payload)=(OMG) already exists.`

Comment: Of course this cannot be done in plain SQL. These functions exist to expose theSQLCA/SQLDA to *any kind* of frontend. (even the text-only `psql` interface handles them)

Comment: Because it was **not** inserted. The transaction is rolled back, including attempted work by triggers, etc. Even if you were able to fetch the VerboseMessage, you would not be able to use it in (subsequent) SQL, because you cannot submit to an aborted transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible even in theory.

Not all constraint failures involve data outside the row being inserted.  For instance, CHECK constraints often will not.  There would be no row id to report in this case.

An INSERT could fail multiple constraints applied to different rows in other tables.  Which one would you be interested in?

If there's a way to find out what *table* a row is in based on the row id, I don't know what it is, so having the raw row id would probably not be much use.

Finally, row ids are optional in SQLite; you can create a table with the row id column using `WITHOUT ROWID`.

Comment: I understand that it's not _always_ possible. But in my specific use case I copy data from one database to another, and any "general" constraints were already met and won't lead to errors. The copy has added tables that may have `unique` constraints, and my (ordered) inserts would then indeed point to one specific failed row (without depenencies on other tables) due to those added constraints. But I accept that there is no such provision in SQL (SQLite, Postgresql), so my tool won't be perfect. Best I can do is to test whether I could detect the failed row, and `RAISE`otherwise.